# Hyper-V Ethernet connection to remote host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ethernet, hyper-v

I have an issue I can't seem to fix and haven't really found much information related to it. I need to connect from a Kali Linux Hyper-V VM, through the host,  to an Ethernet cable connected computer.

Currently my setup allows for connection internally on the NIC from the Host to the VM though the internal switch which makes sense. But because the remote computer can't access that internal virtual switch I'm not sure how to gain access to it.

Current set-up:

- Host IP: 10.1.1.10/24
- Kali VM IP: 10.1.1.9/24
- Host Ethernet IP:10.1.1.100/24
- Remote IP: 10.1.1.99/24

Some other information: I can not connect to the internet all computers must stay offline, eventually I may be able to set up a switch/router but currently that is not feasible, and the Kali VM must be able to connect and attack the Ethernet connected machine.

How can I connect to the remote computer?

Comment: You'll need to set up an external virtual switch and assign it to a NIC for any external access.  You could set up a second NIC and directly connect it to the remote computer via ethernet and then set up an external virtual switch for that NIC and remove the host's access to it.  That would keep it off the network and allow for it to connect to the remote host.  Of course, you'll need to manually deal with the TCP/IP info for both your VM and the remote host.

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up an external virtual switch and assign it to a NIC for any external access. 
You could set up a second NIC to the host PC and then directly connect it to the remote computer via an Ethernet calbe.  Next, set up an external virtual switch for the newly added second NIC and remove the host's access to it. (This could be just not checking the option "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter.")

This would keep the VM off the network and allow for it to connect to the remote host. 
Of course, you'll need to manually enter the TCP/IP info for both your VM and the remote host to allow for a successful TCP/IP connection.